# пишу тему на wordpress, возникли сложности с sidebar

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Пишу тему на wordpress, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться почему  у меня НЕ отображается на сайте sidebar, хотя в админке он появляется, я его заполняю, сохраняю (кнопка "save"). А на сайте он не отображается...
П.С.: функции и код НЕ связанный с sidebar я НЕ писал

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Font-awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/style/mystyle.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/style.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title><?php wp_title (" "); ?>  <?php if (wp_title (" ", false)) { echo " | "; } ?><?php bloginfo ("name"); ?></title>

  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- All content on the page -->
  <div id="cont">
```

index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div>
    Some content
  </div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

function.php:

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Right sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="sidebar-header">',
    'after_title' => '</h2><div class="text">',
    'after_widget' => '</div></div><hr/>'
));
}
```

sidebar.php:

```
        <?php
          if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !is_dynamic_sidebar(1) ) : endif;
        ?>
```

footer.php:

```
        <h1>FOOTER</h1>          
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в `sidebar.php` нет кода вывода виджетов. Исправьте на следующий код.

sidebar.php:

```
    <?php
      if ( is_dynamic_sidebar() ) : dynamic_sidebar(); endif;
    ?>
```